# Applying the l'hospitals rule

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate by applying l'hospitals rule  $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x+\cos x-e^x}{\log(1+x^2)}\\
=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x(\cos x-\sin x-e^x)}{1+x^2}=0$$

But the answer sheet says that answer is $-1$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it's quite incorrect. When you take the derivative of the log term, actually, the $1+x^2$ appears in the numerator...and that's just a start

Comment: Okay, boom. What have I become

Comment: Put the $1+x^2$ in the numerator (you know why...) and the $2x$ in the denom and apply the Rule one more time. I did just that and your $-1$ will appear...

Comment: Apply L'Hospital's rule twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first l'Hospital you get:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-\sin x-e^x}{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x^2)\left(\cos x-\sin x-e^x\right)}{2x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x\left(\cos x-\sin x-e^x\right)+(1+x^2)(-\sin x-\cos x-e^x)}2=\frac{1(-1-1)}{2}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x-> 0} \frac{sinx+cosx-e^x}{log(1+x^2)}\\
=lim_{x->0} \frac{(1+x^2)(cosx-sinx-e^x)}{2x}$$

Comment: that $=0$ should not be there